# Помогите, пожалуйста, не могу получить данные через Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, requests, beautiful-soup, bs4

Я собираю данные с сайта через BeautifulSoup и  requests. Делаю запрос, но мне выходит только HTML строка без текста. Я перепробовал уже десятки способов, но все равно данные не выходят. Прикрепил выходные данные и код снизу.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить проблему?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = 'http://www.licey2perm.ru/'

r = requests.get(url)
html = BS(r.text, 'html.parser')
address = html.find('div', {'class': 'title', 'data-bind': "text: title"})

print(address)
```

Выходит: `<div class="title" data-bind="text: title"></div>`
А должен отдать: `<h3 class="title" data-bind="html: title">Расписание на 24.01.2022-28.01.2022</h3>`

Comment: Почему это должен отдать `<h3>` если вы запрашиваете `<div>`? Да и `'data-bind'` тоже другое значение имеет.

Comment: потому что данные загружаются позже! Используйте Selenuim

Answer (score 2):

> pip install requests-html

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

s = HTMLSession()

url = 'http://www.licey2perm.ru/'

r = s.get(url)

r.html.render(sleep=5, scrolldown=True)

html = BS(r.html.raw_html, 'html.parser')
address = html.find_all('div', {'class': 'title', 'data-bind': "text: title"})
print(*[item.get_text(strip=True) for item in address], sep='\n')
```

Вывод

```latex
Расписание на 24.01.2022-28.01.2022
Итоги недели иностранных языков и фестиваля языков  «В мире языков и языки в мире»
19.01 - встреча с представителем МФПУ "Синергия"
Расписание на 17.01 - 21.01.2022
Попробуй себя в роли: репортера, редактора, фотокорреспондента
Дополнительный набор в 10 фил и 10 Б. Сроки
Подготовительные курсы по химии отменяются
Расписание на 10.01-14.01.2022
C 24/09/2021 проводятся консультации по предметам
```

Answer (score 1):

Прежде чем парсить данные "супом", нужно проверять, доступны ли они при отключенном JavaScript. В вашем случае не доступны, поэтому без открытия браузера они не загружены в DOM. Выход - использовать Selenium webdriver.